# Unable to connect to MySQL from Ejabberd installed in Ubuntu machine. AWS - EC2

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ejabberd

I have installed Ejabberd in Ubuntu machine (An Amazon EC2 machine). I have another machine which is a windows server  and I am running MySQL in it. The service is up and running.

But for some reasons when I start Ejabberd, I am not able to connect to MySQL db which is at the windows machine. I made sure the ports are opened (3306 from the MYSQL machine).

Also, all the neccesary beam files are configured in Ejabberd Ubuntu machine. Not sure why I am not able to connect to MySQL. The error which I get in the log is below. Any help would be great. I have configured the security group in Windows machine to accept request to port 3306 also. Still not able to connect. Thanks for your help

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2014-04-21 00:38:16 ===
E(<0.1005.0>:ejabberd_odbc:542) : mysql_conn: Failed connecting to "172.31.15.211":3306        : {error,
                                                                                           "timeout"}

=ERROR REPORT==== 2014-04-21 00:38:16 ===
E(<0.292.0>:ejabberd_odbc:542) : mysql_conn: post_start timeout


=INFO REPORT==== 2014-04-21 00:38:16 ===
I(<0.292.0>:ejabberd_odbc:216) : mysql connection failed:
** Reason: "timed out"
** Retry after: 30 seconds

=WARNING REPORT==== 2014-04-21 00:38:16 ===
W(<0.292.0>:ejabberd_odbc:281) : unexpected info in connecting: {mysql_conn,
                                                             <0.1014.0>,
                                                             {error,
                                                              connect_failed}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check your mysql configuration file **my.ini** file in windows case

- locate you my.cnf or in windows case my.ini file that should
  locate these setting in my.ini , comment out the **#skip-networking** and in your case bind your IP address

  bind-address            = 0.0.0.0 (Your IP)

Second thing your should give the permission of that user to connect the in mysql

```
GRANT ALL ON DatabaeName.* TO DBUser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
flush privileges;
```

Restart your mysql , let me know how it goes

Comment: @abaid778- Thanks a lot for replying. I was refreshing this page from morning. #skip-networking is already commented in my.ini file. Also, I am not able to find a line bind-address in my.ini. Please let me know whether i need to add a line. Also, I have executed the GRANT ALL sql. Thanks once again and please let me know how to proceed.

Comment: Have added the line bind-address. Still facing the same issue. Any hint to resolve this will be helpful.

Comment: To add some more info on the issue, these 2 machines are AWS EC2 machines hosted in the same VPC. Have made sure the windows machine in which MYSQL server is running has 3306 opened and Inbound rules are modified accordingly.

Comment: @Timothy Rajan... Make sure mysql is restart. Yes you need to add bind-address = 0.0.0.0 and Also check the port number 3306. Now we should start troubleshot the problem. Like first check the opening ports on window machine . Let me know are you saw 3306 opened command for window is netstat -a . Second from your ubuntu machine telnet command should be telnet HOSTIP 3306. Please check the result . let me know . Also one thing make sure you GRANT User permission in mysql the to access remotely which I mention earlier GRANT ALL ON DatabaeName.* TO DBUser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

Comment: @adaid778 - Thanks a lot. Got a big breakthrough. I must admit I am a windows guy  and telnet saved my life. The issue is I am not able to contact the mysql server from DB.

Comment: This is what I get when I telnet "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out"

Comment: I some how believe this is a Firewall issue. Not sure it is from Ubuntu's end or from Windows End. Pls. let me know how to proceed further. Thanks for your help

Comment: OK I think we are in right road to solve this problem. Now Please go to windows Machine and go to run and type cmd , DOS will be open please check the open port on windows node . command would be netstat -a. After that go to AWS console and select the windows Instance please do verify the Security group attached to that windows instance. and then go to that security group which is attached to windows Instance. and select that security group when you select that security group in bottom menu bar second tab is inbond go there and check the inbond allowed traffic . let me know how it goes

Comment: We have firewall or mysql setting issue on window node  where we install mysql please do follow my above comment and let me know how it goes

Comment: Please find the result of netstat below "TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           WIN-VUPPA2ICVAC:0      LISTENING"

Comment: Ok so Its prove that windows Machine is allowed that Please go to AWS console AWS console and select the windows Instance please do verify the Security group attached to that windows instance. and then go to that security group which is attached to windows Instance. and select that security group when you select that security group in bottom menu bar second tab is inbond go there and check the inbond allowed traffic

Comment: @abaid778- This is the info which I get from AWS Console in security group Type:MYSQL
Protocol:TCP
Port:3306
Source:0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Can I disable the firewall settings in Ubuntu and give a try? Please let me know your suggestions. Or is there a way to tweak the settings in Ubuntu. Both Ubuntu and Windows fall into the same network and security group. And the outbound rule is to connect to any machine. (0.0.0.0/0). Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok Ports are open on windows and AWS console. So Last thing is mysql now ... Lets start with mysql 1: Make sure you [mysqld]
port= 3306

Comment: can you paste my.ini [mysqld] setting

Comment: Yes. it is . Just checked. Pasting for your reference

Comment: [client]
no-beep

# pipe
# socket=mysql
port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=utf8

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

Comment: [mysqld]

# The next three options are mutually exclusive to SERVER_PORT below.
# skip-networking
# enable-named-pipe
# The Pipe the MySQL Server will use
# socket=mysql

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306

Comment: ok how you execute the mysql command which utility you are using ?

Comment: I have installed mysql using the installer for windows. The version is the latest version and I am using workbench to create connection and to run sql commands. I am not sure whether this answers your question. Also, I use to start and stop the service using the Service Start/Stop feature which is inbuilt in installer. Let me know if this is not the information you are looking for.

Comment: please execute these command again and please share result
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWOR';
flush privileges;

Comment: Let me know how it goes otherwise need to test that fast on skype... :) skype ID = abaid778

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to execute the query.